# How to redirect on different view on refresh in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, partial-page-refresh

i'm developing an application in AngularJS. Basically, i have a "home" page and a "new project". In the home page i have a menu with a link to "new project".

I configured the $stateProvider as follows :

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.jsp'
}).state('newproject', {
    url: '/newproject',
    templateUrl: 'partials/new-project.html'
})
```

So, when i enter the app, i'm in the home page. Then i click on "new project" link and i'm in the "new project" page. Now the url is *http://myapp/newproject*

My problem is, when i refresh the page, i want to be redirected on the home page, even if the url in my browser bar is still  *http://myapp/newproject*

How can i achieve that?

**UPDATE :**

Thank you very much **squiroid** for your answer. I used the second solution and it worked like a charm. A little clarification, just in case someone should have the same problem, before redirecting to home you have to prevent default operation. So the correct working code is :

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 

if(next==current && next=='/newproject')
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('home');
```

});

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this in your controller of 'newproject' it is listening your refresh:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
     $state.go('home');
});
```

or put this in app.run();

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 

    if(next==current && next=='/newproject')
        $state.go('home');

});
```

Comment: Welcome please mark it and upvote if you satisfy :-)
And +1 for event.preventDefault() i forgot.

Comment: marked! sorry i can't upvote because of reputation points ( i'm < 15 )

Comment: Its fine nice to help you out.

Comment: The first one didn't work for me, the second alternative works with _$location.url("/Home")_ instead of the _$state_ call.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Had to use `$location.url` instead of `$state.go` in my particular case, but paired with `event.preventDefault()`. Thanks.