# How to redirect to home view after page refresh - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question Background:**

I have encountered what seems to be a common issue with AngularJS where I am implementing:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
```

This has removed the '#' from my URL routes and in-turn caused a 404 error. I fixed that by adjusting web.config and the page reloads now.

**The Issue:**

I have a 2 views called `Home.html` and `Results.html`. I also have a index.html which houses the in my app which houses a `<div ui-view>` where the home and result views are injected into.

The following is the routes used:

```
http://localhost:5XXXX/ - home
http://localhost:5XXXX/results - results
```

I want to redirect to the home.html view when results.html is refreshed. Currently when results.html is refreshed all of y scope data is lost along with jquery plugin object state in the directives.

**The Code:**

app.js - this houses the routes of the app:

```
 angular
  .module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngResource',
    'rzModule',
    'angular-ladda',
    'jcs-autoValidate'
  ])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })


          $stateProvider.state('results', {
              url: '/results',
              templateUrl: 'Results.html',
              controller: 'ResultsController'
          })

          $locationProvider.html5Mode({
              enabled: true,
              requireBase: false
          });
    }]);
```

ResultsController.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('ResultsController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, $anchorScroll, $window, searchService) {

    //code

});
```

**If I refresh the `Results.html` page how can I immediately redirect to the `Home.html` view instead of reloading the `Results.html` page?**

**EDIT:**

I have updated the ResultsController.js with the following but this code does not seem to be called on a reload, it does not redirect to home.

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('ResultsController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, $anchorScroll, $window, searchService) {

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
        $state.go('/');
    });
});
```

Also to add I have added the following to the Web.config of my app to handle rerouting:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $locationChangeStart

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
   $state.go('/');
});
```

Proper code :  $locationChangeStart **run**
Put this in main app file and attach it to app like app.config do it like app.run()

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state, userService) {
       $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
          if(next == current) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.transitionTo('/');
            }
       });
}]);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Where does this code need to be placed? In the ResultsController.js?

Comment: Yes buddy  ! and if you want to go with run just write it in your main app file after .config()  write .run()

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I have edited my original post with the edit. This still is not redirecting to the home page though.

Comment: Try this one buddy which I just edited my answer and I have tested in my local machine. It works  !!  Put the run function in app.js  like app.run(...)

Answer (score 1):

some pseudo code

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('ResultsController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, $anchorScroll, $window, searchService, $state) {
  if (data unavailable) {
    $state.go('home');
  }
});
```

if your results data isn't available just do $state.go('home'); in the `ResultsController`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ronnie. I did think about just checking the $scope data and if it was null then return like you show. Would that be a valid way of doing this?

Comment: I don't see why not. I've done it before in the past. Charli's answer would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that's been answered here: [How to redirect on different view on refresh in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072092/how-to-redirect-on-different-view-on-refresh-in-angularjs)

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 

if(next==current && next=='/results')
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('home');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have placed this within my results controller but it never seems to trigger? The code is never hit.

Comment: If there is a duplicate, please flag as such.